# Azure redis cache secondary database. Not able to access

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache

I have a Azure redis cache of premium subscription. I can connect to primary cache (database id=0) via the stack exchange redis code but not able to connect to the secondary cache. I get an error especially while clearing the cache.

Earlier i was using the class Azure cache where by i could clear the secondary cache. But accessing the Azure redis secondary cache is giving an error.

Can anyone help? I read somewhere that the redis cache has only got a primary cache?

Comment: Please include the error message that you're getting.

Comment: Hi Gaurav. Sorry..it seems that the code is behaving in a strange way ..in the sense that when i am debugging with the app running on Azure, the control seems to go haywire (lots of requests) and thats the reason i am not able to recreate the error at the moment.

Comment: Hi gaurav...i am now able to reproduce the error. But i have posted this now in a different thread. Can you please guide me on this. 
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54697288/splitting-azure-redis-cache-into-primary-and-secondary-cache