# Splitting Azure Redis Cache into Primary and secondary cache

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-redis-cache

Team,

Beginner in Azure. I am running a Azure web app referencing a azure redis cache. Now i have a requirement whereby i have to load the colleagues data into  the primary cache upon the first load and any updates to the colleagues count is loaded in the secondary cache. Once completed a swap is done where by the change in the value of the primary key value.

So i have implemented in such a way that it will first identify which is primary and which is secondary. ( Please note that i am not sure if this approach is correct or not). I have introduced a primary key value for that matter. So i use the code below

```
try 
{ 
    IServer server = cacheFactory.GetServer(getEndPoint(), null); //TODO read from config 
    var StoreCache = cacheFactory.GetDatabase(0, null); 
    StoreCache.StringSet("PrimaryCacheKey",cache.Name); //Set the primary cache key to be whatever this cache is 
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    this.Logger.Error(ex, "Error setting primary cache."); 
    throw; 
}
```

But this throws an error saying "Object not set to reference of the object). When i debug the value of the cache.Name= 1. Why does it not find the cache.Name  when i am trying to set the key for this.

Any other suggestions welcome please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it sounds like exactly the issue which is already tracked in the `StackExchange.Redis` repository. So, I suggest that you could update your nuget version and restart it.

For more details, you could refer to this similar [issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/424).

Comment: Thanks...I used the latest version of stack excahnge redis and secondly noticed that the redis cache was beneath a Virtual network. I create a new redis cache from scartch without a virtual network and all was ok!